# pyspark 1.6.3 linear regression error float() argument must be a string or number

Tags: python, pyspark, linear-regression

i am using linear regression from pyspark this is my code :

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LabeledPoint,LinearRegressionWithSGD
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
import time
import csv

start_time = time.time()

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("project_spark").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

X_train = sc.textFile('C:\Users\WINDOWS 8.1\Desktop\BoW_Train_int_1k.csv')
X_test = sc.textFile('C:\Users\WINDOWS 8.1\Desktop\BoW_Test_int_1k.csv')
y_train = sc.textFile('C:\Users\WINDOWS 8.1\Desktop\Train_Tags81_1k.csv')
y_test = sc.textFile('C:\Users\WINDOWS 8.1\Desktop\Test_Tags81_1k.csv')

X_train = X_train.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
X_test = X_test.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
y_train = y_train.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
y_test = y_test.map(lambda line: line.split(","))

training = LabeledPoint(y_train, X_train)
testing = LabeledPoint(y_test, X_test)

model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(training)
valuesAndPreds = (testing.map(lambda p: (p.label, model.predict(p.features))))

evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse")
RMSE = evaluator.evaluate(valuesAndPreds)

print("Root Mean Squared Error = " + str(RMSE))
Time = time.time() - start_time
print("--- %s seconds ---" % Time)
spark.stop()
```

but this code have error float() argument must be a string or number in line

```
training = LabeledPoint(y_train, X_train)
```

so,how can i fix it

Comment: Please explain more in detail what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Without having the whole picture, my guess is that you are giving `LabeledPoint` the wrong type of arguments. More specifically, your `y_train` and `y_test` get values from the following:

```
...
y_train.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
y_test.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

Each return a `list`, which is not compatible with the `LabeledPoint` `label` argument.

So:
`training = LabeledPoint(y_train, X_train)` --> `training = LabeledPoint([some, values], [some, other, values])`

But, taken from the [docs/source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/regression.html#LabeledPoint), `LabeledPoint` expects the first argument, the label, to be something that can be casted to `float`.

```
class LabeledPoint(object):

    """
    Class that represents the features and labels of a data point.

    :param label:
      Label for this data point.
    :param features:
      Vector of features for this point (NumPy array, list,
      pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector, or scipy.sparse column matrix).

    .. note:: 'label' and 'features' are accessible as class attributes.

    .. versionadded:: 1.0.0
    """

    def __init__(self, label, features):
        self.label = float(label)
        self.features = _convert_to_vector(features)
```

Thus, depending on what your line looks like, maybe change your code to something like the following:

```
...
y_train.map(lambda line: line.split(",")[0])
...
y_test.map(lambda line: line.split(",")[0])
```

Hope that helps, good luck!